# How do i construct a function that has this domain ℝ\(2ℕ-1)?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, graphing-functions

I was trying a lot of things like $f(x)=1/\sin(π((x+1)/2))$ etc. but i always got all odd integers out of the domain.

Comment: Confusing. You decide what the domain is as long as it is permitted. E.g take any well-defined map on $\mathbb R$ and restrict to any subset you wish.

Comment: It is one of the problems on Real analysis exam about 10 years old. It must be answered using only one function.

Comment: Probably it is ment to find a functional rule so that the maximal possible domain is $\mathbb{R}\backslash (2\mathbb{N}-1)$

Comment: Question goes like this: "Find an elementary function whose natural domain is the set R\(2N − 1)."

Comment: @AlvinL than i really don't know how to do it. I tried with trig and failed every time. Maybe the question is flawed.